# Simplehtmldom parsing <pre> but got error

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I got this kind of code in website target

http://lufy.byethost6.com/tes.html

And using this code to parse it

```
<?php 
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html('http://lufy.byethost6.com/tes.html');
$ret = $html->find('pre',0);
echo $ret;
?>
```

When I saw the result its became one line like this

```
  title goes here    Intro : Gm Cm           Gm Cm       Gm                                  Cm  lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics,     Gm                   Cm  lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics
```

I want the result same look like the target site

```
title goes here

Intro : Gm Cm 
        Gm Cm 


Gm                                  Cm
lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, 
  Gm                   Cm
lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics, lyrics
```

Is it possible?

Comment: When you view source of the page you are generating, is there a pre tag around the content?

Comment: yup when parse the pre code still exist on the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set flag `$stripRN` to false,bacause by default, line breaks
tags are stripped out. Change to:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://lufy.byethost6.com/tes.html', $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=false, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT);
```

Comment: thanks its work :) where i can find reference about that $stripRN mate? i want to read it

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use

```
echo $ret->outertext;
```

See http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm